# How can I declare a class variable as floating point in Moose?

Tags: perl, floating-point, moose

How can I declare a class variable as floating point in Moose?

My (fictional) sample below produces errors for "Real", "Number" etc ... "Str" works but defeats the purpose .. searching/Google doesn't help, since I can't hit the correct search terms...

---

**PROBLEM.pm**

```
package PROBLEM;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Moose;

has 'PROBLEM'=> (isa=>'real',is =>'ro',required=>'0',default=>sub {0.1;});
```

---

**main.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PROBLEM;

my $problem=PROBLEM->new();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the [Moose Types](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Types.pod#THE_TYPES) documentation. There is no built-in float type, just `Num` and its subtype `Int`. This makes sense, since Perl really doesn't differentiate (visibly) between floats and integers.

The best thing to do is probably to use `Num` as the type constraint, or write your own type that coerces the value into some form that suits your needs.

Comment: The official documentation for default types is in the Moose docs:  http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Util/TypeConstraints.pm#Default_Type_Constraints

Answer (score 6):

You need *Num* type for a real number:

```
{
    package Problem;
    use Moose;

    has 'number' => ( 
        isa      => 'Num', 
        is       => 'ro', 
        default  => sub { 0.1 },
    );
}


my $problem = Problem->new;
say $problem->number;  # => 0.1
```